# Error connecting to mongodb container version 6.0.2 | amd64/mongo

Tags: mongodb, docker, go, x86-64, driver

Iam able to connect mongo container versions 4.X and 5.X with the below code using [amd64/mongo](https://hub.docker.com/r/amd64/mongo/)

```
    auth := options.Credential{
        AuthSource: admin,
        Username:   userName,
        Password:   pass,
    }
    opts := options.Client().ApplyURI(URI).SetAuth(auth).SetTLSConfig(&config)
    client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, opts)
```

But when i try to upgrade the container to version 6.0.2 from [amd64/mongo](https://hub.docker.com/r/amd64/mongo/)

It fails with the below error

```
:Unable to connect to thedatabase :connection() error occurred during connection handshake: auth error: sasl conversation error: unable to authenticate using mechanism "SCRAM-SHA-1": (AuthenticationFailed) Authentication failed.
```

I believe by default it tries to pick `SCRAM-SHA-1`

do I need to set a mongoDB server [param](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/parameters/) in my mongo run script file like below ?

```
--authenticationMechanisms=SCRAM-SHA-1
```

All i'm trying to do is connect to db and change the admin and db password using below code , not sure even if this is depreciated now in the mongo version `6.0.2`

```
res := struct{ Ok int }{}
opts := options.RunCmd().SetReadPreference(readpref.Primary())  
command := bson.D{{"updateUser", usrName}, {"pwd", pass}}
err = client.Database(db).RunCommand(context.TODO(), command, opts).Decode(&res)
```

not sure where am i making mistake , the error message is not straight forward . Can anyone help me here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So was able to resolve this , The problem was my scripts were using `mongo` but that is removed in the latest mongo version `6.0` , So i used `mongosh`, when I try to init the mongo container, that worked.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/

Comment: Mongo should improve their error messages